# Referenced DLL In SSIS Script Task - Missing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a script task that is running. I need to swap out the DLL it referenced with an updated DLL. The issue is it's not in the normal places.

**Problem**

A referenced DLL is still working in a script task that wasn't set up by me. I need to update it but have no idea where it is.

**Details**

The SQL Server is running on D Drive of a windows 2008 R2 server. This D Drive only has the SQL Server installed in Program files, and Program files (x86).

**Checked the following places for the active dll**

- C:\Windows\Assembily
- Running GACUTIL via location, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe", command line gacutil -l > output.txt, then searched thought text file.
- Microsoft Sql Server Assembilies, "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies"
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\{{AllVersions}}"

**I thought I found it once in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly" but I replaced it and nothing changed with the script task (updates didn't happen), and I tried using the gacutil.exe located in that folder mentioned above and it was not responsive in Command Line.**

Any Ideas on Where the DLL is Located? Or if I did find it why it doesn't seem to be working properly, I am I missing a step?

NOTE THAT I CHECKED Gacutil mentioned above and the output.txt didn't contain the dll I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps the tea hasn't kicked in, but I read this as "Where is some DLL on my computer?" What DLL are you looking for? How have you looked for it. I would open a command window and at the root of each drive, issue a command like `dir /s /b MyAssembly.dll` You'd also need to look at how you're loading said DLL. Your Script task might have a reference to a specific build of it (v 1.0.0.0) and your new build might be (v 1.0.0.1) and so even if you have the new one out there, the script knows to use the old version.

Comment: I deleted the "old" dll I found. It doesn't matter what ddl it is it's a custom dll for SSIS script task. There is a standard way of using a DLL for a script task. Which is why I am asking if there is another place where the dll can be. Since there seems to be a standard way of loading custom dlls in script task SSIS